# Stop SKROLLR's animation on a specific artibute

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

Sadly, SKROLLR doesn't support `position: fixed;` in it's `skrollr-body` element. `skrollr-body` is the div that moves to fake scroll on mobile. The problem is that I want to do animation on a object with `position: fixed;`, So I thought about adding it:

```
<div data-0="top: 0;" data-1000000="top: 1000000px;"> [...] </div>
```

This will keep the `div` at the top of the page. The problem is that SKROLLR uses animation. I know I can add `smoothScrolling=false`, but I do want animation, on every change except `top`'s changes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! All you need to do is to set `data-smooth-scrolling` to `on` or `off`.

In my example, what I should do is this:

```
<div data-0="top: 0;" data-1000000="top: 1000000px;" data-smooth-scrolling="off"> [...] </div>
```